# Change URL of Hyperlink in ASP.net gridview itemTemplate dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind, itemtemplate

I am creating a UI that contains an itemTemplate w/in a gridView.  inside the ItemTemplate I need a link that will be populated dynamically based on the table values I am binding to the table.  In other words, sometimes the link will point to a file on my server, and sometimes it will point to another URL.  In essence, I need to be able to check a flag on the table I'm binding to the gridview, and then update each rows itemTemplate based on data in the table for the corresponding row.

So far, I have this markup:

```
                 <asp:GridView ID="grdVDocuments" 
                                runat="server" 
                                DataSourceID="sqlDS_wwso" 
                                EnableModelValidation="True" 
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                OnRowDataBound="grdVDocuments_RowDataBound"                      
                                CssClass="documents_DataTable" AllowPaging="True"            
                                >
                    <Columns>                            
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download">
                            <ItemTemplate>

                                <a href="/<%# Eval("fileName") %>" target="_blank" id="lnkContent">
                                   <img src="images/orange_download_cropped.png" alt="" border="0"/></a> 

                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="displayName" HeaderText="displayName" SortExpression="displayName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="fileName" HeaderText="fileName" SortExpression="fileName" />                             
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="category" HeaderText="category" SortExpression="category" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="sub_category" HeaderText="Sub-Category" SortExpression="sub_category" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="datePosted" HeaderText="datePosted" SortExpression="datePosted" />                                                         
                    </Columns>
                 </asp:GridView>
```

and this code-behind, which is bombing because it can't identify the hyperlink

```
    protected void grdVDocuments_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)        
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink myHyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("lnkContent") as HyperLink;

            myHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "<someOtherURL>";

        }
    }
```

The data table has a flag on called isFile which is "bit" dataType.  When isFile=1 the URL needs to be ".../", otherwise the URL in the hyperlink of the itemtemplate for each row needs to be set to another field in my table that holds a URL; i.e. "someOtherURL".

Any help is appreciated ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a server control inside the ItemTemplate. So, you need to add `runat="server"` attribute to the `a` tag. But then, it is an `HtmlAnchor` element, and you need to cast as `HtmlAnchor` instead of `Hyperlink` like (code-behind):

```
...
var myHyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("lnkContent") as HtmlAnchor;
myHyperLink.HRef = "<someOtherURL>";
...
```

Or, you can use `<asp:Hyperlink>` tag in you aspx markup (instead of html anchor `a`)